# undefined post error in http angular2

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I am trying to post the data to database,but i am getting the error "cannot read the property 'post' of undefined".I am trying to learn angular2 can someone help me.

```js
 import {Component} from '@angular/component'
 import {FormBuilder, Validators, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

 @Component({
   selector: 'profile-form',
   directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
   templateUrl: './components/profile/profile.html',
   providers: [FormBuilder, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
 })
 export class Profile {
   data;
   form;

   constructor(private http: Http) {}
   onSubmit(): void {

     this.http.post(
         'http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/addprofile',
         JSON.stringify({
           firstname: 'bar',
           lastname: 'foo'
         }))
       .subscribe((res: Response) => {
         this.data = res.json();

       });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Have you added HTTP_PROVIDERS in your main AppComponent?

Comment: yes i did that in main app component

Comment: On line 1, you are importing Component from '@angular/component'... this should be '@angular/core'.